# Flex-end doesn't seem to work with flexbox

Tags: reactjs, css, flexbox

I am setting up navigation and I am new to flexbox. I try to have left and right elements with flex-end and flex-start (flex-around seem to have too much space for me). Everything is left aligned and I don't seem to understand what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
<header className="header">
    <div className="leftSide">
    <div className="one">One of left elements</div>
    </div>
    <div className="rightSide">
    <p className="two">One of right elements</p>
    </div>
    </header>

CSS:
.header{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
.leftSide{
    margin-left: 20px; 
    display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start; 

}
.rightSide{
    margin-right: 20px; 
    display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; 

}
```

Comment: nothing wrong but flex item shrink to fit the content (like inline-block) so there is nothing to align

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's not enough to set header width to 100% to align two elements left and right inside of it?

Comment: you are not aligning the element, you are aligning the text inside the element, align-items apply to inner items

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry, my bad. I was trying to align elements. I replaced align-items with justify-content but it doesn't seems to do anything as well.

Comment: you need to apply them to parent container :) that's what am trying to explain. Justify-content and align-items are the same, need to be specified on the flex container

Comment: @TemaniAfif I kinda understand what you are saying but at the same time if I have only one parent element and two children then I can't use both flex-end and flex-end for that one parent unless I use space-around or space-between. Somehow I was able to achieve what I want by setting margin-left: auto to the rightSide element :)

Comment: just use for leftSide margin-right:auto and for rightSide margin-left:auto.